# Code stops at MyObjectBox.build() but no error

Tags: android, objectbox

My app is having issues which may or may not be down to ObjectBox.

I have made a tiny code change, completely unrelated to ObjectBox but when my app starts there is just a black screen. I've put a lot of logging around the initial lines of code, and I think there is something going wrong at the `build()` command, though there is nothing in the error log around this.

My code is

```
public class DB {

    private File boxStoreDir;
    private static BoxStore store;

    public DB() {
        try {
            Gdx.app.error("aidan","8a");
            createMyObjectBox();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Gdx.app.error("aidan"," error 8a - "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createMyObjectBox() throws IOException {
        FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.local("objectstorefile");
        Gdx.app.error("aidan","8b - file="+fileHandle.path());
        if(!fileHandle.isDirectory()) {
            Gdx.app.error("aidan","8b1 - having to call fileHandle.mkdirs()");
            fileHandle.mkdirs();
        }
        boxStoreDir = fileHandle.file();

        if(store == null) {
            Gdx.app.error("aidan","8c - MyObjectBox.builder().directory(boxStoreDir).build()");
            store = MyObjectBox.builder().directory(boxStoreDir).build();
            Gdx.app.error("aidan","8d - store="+store.getNativeStore());
        }
    }
}
```

and the error logs show...

```
02-19 20:59:02.052 16625 16694 E aidan   : 8
02-19 20:59:02.052 16625 16694 E aidan   : 8a
02-19 20:59:02.052 16625 16780 W Ads     : Not retrying to fetch app settings
02-19 20:59:02.054 16625 16694 E aidan   : 8b - file=objectstorefile
02-19 20:59:02.054 16625 16694 E aidan   : 8c - MyObjectBox.builder().directory(boxStoreDir).build()
02-19 20:59:02.055  4439  4977 W GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 200414000, Services 200414037, and Games 157090048
02-19 20:59:02.070  4439 14826 W Ads     : App does not have the required permissions to get location
02-19 20:59:02.078 16625 16662 D skia    : --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
02-19 20:59:02.080  4439  4569 I PeopleChimeraService: onService. callbacks = zwr@66e7b0d, request = com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GetServiceRequest@f968ac2
```

Answer (score 0):

"App does not have the required permissions to get location" seems relevant.

Please try the [Android standard way to build ObjectBox](https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started#core-initialization):

```
    boxStore = MyObjectBox.builder()
            .androidContext(context.getApplicationContext())
            .build();
```

Does that work?

Comment: So technically I'm not making an Android app...it's a lot to explain but I'm using the gaming library LibGDX in which you write your code in a 'core' module that is plain Java. Then you run that inside an Android Activity, so it's kind of nested in there, but it's not actually an Android app. I can potentially try it though... (but it's been working for over a year without needing to do that).

Also the location one wouldn't stop the code at ObjectBox though, right? That's just a warning from Admob, and there's more Ad stuff that happens later on

Comment: Sorry, struggling to do that easily. It would mean a massive rewrite of my code, days of work. Plus it works fine on most peoples devices, my own including, it's just two of my testers it fails on. The app doesn't crash though, it just sits there with a black screen.

Comment: OK, if that won't work quickly; I have questions... So you never get to see "8d" in the logs right? Usually the logs are reliable to show crashes, e.g. exceptions or native crashes. Are you sure the logs don't show any relevant info later? Check log entries for your app's process ID. This is standard Android logcat? Can you debug into build() to see if and where it goes bad?

Comment: yes never get to see 8d, not any other log markers I have put in later after the DB class constructor. I was scrolling through the logs based on the process ID and I can't see anything that stands out. Unfortunately I can't run the debugger, as it works fine on my own device, this is on one of my testers. He is a dev so he used `adb logcat` and grabbed the logs for me. I know this isn't much to go on, sorry

Comment: One additional thing that I think is unrelated, using Android Studio, MyObjectBox and all the generated MyEntity_ classes are always red, as if the imports don't exist, but they do and the app compiles perfectly. It's not like that in my server project in intelliJ. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that using LibGDX swallows exceptions (or only during some setup stage)? E.g. try explicitly throwing to see if there would be log output on a release build. Android Studio: probably due to limited support for plain Java modules.

Comment: Do you mean wrap the MyObjectBox.build() in a try/catch block? Or you just mean throw an exception and see if it appears in any logs at all? Ok, on the Android Studio, I guess nothing I can do about that one, thanks